# How to draw (and paint) the Voronoi regions of a series of points using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw (and paint) Voronoi regions of a series of points in plane using Tikz? How about if the points are in 3d space?

Comment: do you want a completely automatic way?
Would some manual geometric construction be ok?
Algorithms to do it are usually either inefficient or require rich data-structures which are difficult to code in TeX. For a completely automatic solution I would recommend generating the coordinates of the diagram from an external tool (or using LuaTeX?)

Comment: @Bordaigorl I prefer an automatic tool and I am not familiar with LuaTeX capabilities. Matlab has some tools for this, but I prefer to be able to do it on a PC with no Matlab.

Comment: You could also specify your requirements: does it need to be fast? How many points on average? Are you trying to draw a specific voronoi diagram or actually generate diagrams as needed? Is there a reason why you want to do it in TikZ or it's just that you want the "graphical rendering" to be done in TikZ?

Comment: I think that the first part of this question is clear : given a set of points, how can we draw the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) ? The 3D part is not clear. This question can be edited in a way to make it clear ... but for this it must be reopened ;)

Comment: For the 2D Voronoi diagram, see [Is there a way to draw a Voronoi diagram with pgfplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228233/2552) (uses Octave/Matlab and PGFPlots).

Answer (score 12):

Here is one solution using TikZ.

```
\documentclass[preview, border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xinttools} % for the \xintFor***
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\def\biglen{20cm} % playing role of infinity (should be < .25\maxdimen)
% define the "half plane" to be clipped (#1 = half the distance between cells)
\tikzset{
  half plane/.style={ to path={
       ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!(\tikztotarget)!\biglen!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
    -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!(\tikztotarget)!\biglen!-90:(\tikztotarget)$)
    -- ([turn]0,2*\biglen) -- ([turn]0,2*\biglen) -- cycle}},
  half plane/.default={1pt}
}

\def\n{23} % number of random points
\def\maxxy{4} % random points are in [-\maxxy,\maxxy]x[-\maxxy,\maxxy]

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % generate random points
    \pgfmathsetseed{1908} % init random with the year Voronoi published his paper ;)
    \def\pts{}
    \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\n}} \do{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ptx}{.9*\maxxy*rand} % random x in [-.9\maxxy,.9\maxxy]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\pty}{.9*\maxxy*rand} % random y in [-.9\maxxy,.9\maxxy]
      \edef\pts{\pts, (\ptx,\pty)} % stock the random point
    }

    % draw the points and their cells
    \xintForpair #1#2 in \pts \do{
      \edef\pta{#1,#2}
      \begin{scope}
        \xintForpair \#3#4 in \pts \do{
          \edef\ptb{#3,#4}
          \ifx\pta\ptb\relax % check if (#1,#2) == (#3,#4) ?
            \tikzstyle{myclip}=[];
          \else
            \tikzstyle{myclip}=[clip];
          \fi;
          \path[myclip] (#3,#4) to[half plane] (#1,#2);
        }
        \clip (-\maxxy,-\maxxy) rectangle (\maxxy,\maxxy); % last clip
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\randhue}{rnd}
        \definecolor{randcolor}{hsb}{\randhue,.5,1}
        \fill[randcolor] (#1,#2) circle (4*\biglen); % fill the cell with random color
        \fill[draw=red,very thick] (#1,#2) circle (1.4pt); % and draw the point
      \end{scope}
    }
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \draw (-\maxxy,-\maxxy) rectangle (\maxxy,\maxxy);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments on the code :

- Given two points, A and B, the points that are closer to A is a half plane, delimited by the [perpendicular bisector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector), and containing A.
- So to construct the Voronoi cell of A we can take the intersection of all this half planes when B runs over all other points (different from A).
- In the code, taking this intersection is done by clipping big rectangles that plays the role of "half planes".
- I was not able to use `\foreach` because clipping inside such a loop is not available outside the loop (`\foreach` creates a group). So I'm overcoming this by using `\xintFor`.

Comment: Nice. It is if I'm not wrong `O(n^2)` complexity but it should do for small number of samples although I would simply call Lua or Python and be done with it. And by the way infinity is kept under the register `\maxdimen`.

Comment: @percusse Yes O(n^2). I'll be happy to see here LuaTeX, PythonTeX, metapost or another solution that is faster ;)

Comment: My concern is more to the fact that it is consuming PDF objects rather too quickly. Speed is TeX speed anyways. I had a half answer with pgfplots. I'll try to find it.

Comment: @percusse actually `\biglen` should be smaller than `.25\maxdimen`.

Comment: @percusse Ah ok. For example for 50 points this is ~2500 PDF objects and a file of ~50k. Is this unreasonable ?

Comment: Maybe you could edit some of what you rolled back into your answer? Especially to explain what Voronoi points/regions are. Unless I'm the only one who was not familiar with this terminology?