# Is there a way to draw a Voronoi diagram with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, matlab

I want to draw a voronoi diagram with pgfplots, but sadly I cannot get it the way it should look like. I used the Matlab command to get the x and y coordinates and saved them as a dat-file. In that file I stored the x coordinates in the first column and the y coordinates in the second column.

[image: Matlab output: How I would like to have it]

[image: pgfplots output: Snapshot how it looks like right now]

Does anyone have an idea, how it could work?

Minimal Example of the Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,shapes,arrows,external,3d,patterns,spy}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
  -7.9265104e+00   3.6503989e-01
   4.3133971e-01   9.4062409e-01
  -7.9265104e+00   3.6503989e-01
   6.3976919e-02   5.4947497e-01
   6.3976919e-02   5.4947497e-01
   3.0293735e-01   6.5037024e-01
   3.6748619e-01   9.5786833e-02
   6.3976919e-02   5.4947497e-01
   3.0293735e-01   6.5037024e-01
   4.0645496e-01   8.2958752e-01
   4.9066479e-01   4.4410036e-01
   3.0293735e-01   6.5037024e-01
   3.6748619e-01   9.5786833e-02
   4.9244296e-01   2.3488102e-01
   4.9244296e-01   2.3488102e-01
   4.9066479e-01   4.4410036e-01
   4.9066479e-01   4.4410036e-01
   7.3082954e-01   5.1825327e-01
   1.8829507e+00   1.7053562e-01
   4.9244296e-01   2.3488102e-01
   4.3133971e-01   9.4062409e-01
   8.7230061e-01   2.0371867e+00
   4.0645496e-01   8.2958752e-01
   4.3133971e-01   9.4062409e-01
   6.6251849e-01   6.4842135e-01
   4.0645496e-01   8.2958752e-01
   6.9696115e-01   6.8938388e-01
   8.7230061e-01   2.0371867e+00
   7.3082954e-01   5.1825327e-01
   6.6251849e-01   6.4842135e-01
   1.8829507e+00   1.7053562e-01
   7.3082954e-01   5.1825327e-01
   6.6251849e-01   6.4842135e-01
   6.9696115e-01   6.8938388e-01
  -7.9265104e+00   3.6503989e-01
  -1.7371176e+01   8.6111447e-02
   3.6748619e-01   9.5786833e-02
  -6.0998602e-02  -1.3709259e+00
   1.8829507e+00   1.7053562e-01
   4.4291165e+00  -2.9045575e-01
   8.7230061e-01   2.0371867e+00
   1.8287612e+00   4.5227847e+00
   6.9696115e-01   6.8938388e-01
   1.9370861e+00   1.3452721e+00
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=3cm, y=3cm, z=0cm, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3 [color=blue, samples y=0] file {voronoi.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Googling 'tikz voronoi' leads to [Using datatool and TikZ to generate figures from data](https://axiomatic.neophilus.net/posts/2013-03-16-using-datatool-and-tikz-to-generate-figures-from-data.html), which shows an example with a MATLAB-generated dataset.

Comment: In addition to Mike Renfro's comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks Mike Renfro for suggesting Google. Like I did not think about that first. Thank you Christian Hupfer for offering your help! I add a minimal example to my question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but we don't have that data file, and you've given no indication of what "the way it should look like" actually _is_. Please add some sample data that we can work with and explain what you want to change of the output from the code/data in your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will do that in just a minute.

Comment: If I hadn't mentioned what I googled (specifically not knowing if you checked for both tikz and pgfplots solutions), should I have assumed you'd already seen the link I posted and found something wrong with it? No way to know from what you'd originally posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an empty line between the individual line segments of the Voronoi diagram so the line segments aren't connected.

Say you have the following file 'points.dat' containing the coordinates of the points you want to draw the Voronoi diagram for:

```
1   4
4   1
2   6
3   5
4   3
6   2
```

Then you can find the Voronoi diagram using Matlab or Octave like so:

```ml
points = dlmread('points.dat');
[vx, vy] = voronoi(points(:,1), points(:,2));
```

To write this to a file that can be plotted using PGFPlots, you can use

```ml
fid = fopen('voronoi.dat', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%f %f\n%f %f\n\n', [vx(:), vy(:)]');
fclose(fid);
```

In PGFPlots, you can then create the plot like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image
]
\addplot [only marks, red] table {points.dat};
\addplot [no markers, update limits=false] table {voronoi.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you also get the feeling that we can do this in pgfplotstable from scratch :) ?

Comment: @percusse: Sure, how hard can that be... [oh...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode)

Comment: Bah details, details... Partypooper :P

Comment: @Jake: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. You just forgot to save the actual data to the file in your example. This should do it:
`fprintf(fid,'%f %f\n%f %f\n\n', [vx(:), vy(:)]');`

Comment: @Guest: Ah yes, you're right. Corrected now

Comment: @Jake Many thanks for your solution. Works like a charm!