# Draw magnetic domain with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am going to draw magnetic domain for paramagnet and ferromagnet as shown in figure below with `tikz` package:

[image]

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\bacterium}[2]{
\begin{scope}[rotate=#2]
\coordinate (A) at (#1);
\draw[-latex](A)++(0,.75*.5)--++(-.75,0);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[](-6,-6)rectangle(6,6);
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,40}{\bacterium{rand*5,rand*5}{rand*360}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: how about shapes of small pieces? is it random?

Comment: You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255899 and add the arrows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a randomly deformed hexagonal lattice to get

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{marrow/.style={red,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow
    head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \clip (1,2) rectangle (7.5,12);
 \path foreach \X in {0,...,12}
 {foreach \Y in {0,...,9}
 {({0.75*\X+ifthenelse(isodd(\X),-1,1)*0.25+0.2*(2*rnd-1)},
 {\Y*sqrt(3)+ifthenelse(isodd(\X),-1,1)*sqrt(3)/4+0.2*(2*rnd-1)})
 coordinate[overlay] (p\X\Y)
 }};
 \foreach \X in {1,3,5,7,9}
 {\foreach \Y in {1,...,7} 
 {\ifodd\Y
 \draw (p\the\numexpr\X-1\relax\Y) coordinate(aux1)
 -- (p\X\Y) coordinate(aux2)
 -- (p\the\numexpr\X+1\relax\the\numexpr\Y-1\relax) coordinate(aux3)
 --  (p\the\numexpr\X+2\relax\Y) coordinate(aux4)
 --  (p\the\numexpr\X+1\relax\Y) coordinate(aux5)
 -- (p\X\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax) coordinate(aux6) -- cycle;
 \else
 \draw (p\X\Y) coordinate(aux1) -- 
 (p\the\numexpr\X+1\relax\the\numexpr\Y-1\relax) coordinate(aux2) -- 
 (p\the\numexpr\X+2\relax\Y) coordinate(aux3) -- 
 (p\the\numexpr\X+1\relax\Y) coordinate(aux4) --
 (p\X\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax) coordinate(aux5) -- 
 (p\the\numexpr\X-1\relax\Y) coordinate(aux6) -- cycle;
 \fi
 \path (barycentric cs:aux1=1,aux2=1,aux3=1,aux4=1,aux5=1,aux6=1) node[rotate=rnd*360,marrow]{};
 }}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have upvoted your answer now. Is it possible to put your code into box (of Schrödinger's cat)? :-)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but can someone explain the code, or point out where to look for more information? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nikos It is hard to explain the code if one does not know which part you do not understand. This code generates lattice points which are shifted by some random distances, and connects them. The result is deformed hexagonal lattice. In each cell at the barycenter of the nodes of the cell boundary an arrow is placed that points in a random direction.